# Finding unique taxonomic counts based on hierarchy

Tags: r, if-statement, subset, taxonomy

I have searched for methods to do this, but using count(unique()) doesn't search other factors. An example dataset is below.

```
df <- data.frame(Site = c("X1", "X1", "X1"), Date = c(2006, 2006, 2006), TaxonID = c("Chironomidae", "Saetheria", "Chimarra"), Family = c("Chironomidae", "Chironomidae", "Philopotamidae"), Genus = c("-", "Saetheria", "Chimarra"), Count = c(2, 1, 5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

+------+------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------+
| Site | Date |   TaxonID    |     Family     |   Genus   | Count |
+------+------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------+
| X1   | 2006 | Chironomidae | Chironomidae   | -         |     2 |
| X1   | 2006 | Saetheria    | Chironomidae   | Saetheria |     1 |
| X1   | 2006 | Chimarra     | Philopotamidae | Chimarra  |     5 |
+------+------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------+
```

Counting TaxonID would over count, since in this case row 1 should not be counted due to something identified lower than that taxonomic level, i.e. row 2.

In this dataset, counting the unique values in Genus will work, but in an example where row 2 is not present, this will not.

This is a truncated table, where normally Phylum, Class, and Order are also present, and TaxonID may be something in one of those fields.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking.

Comment: I was afraid I wasn't being clear enough. I'm basically looking to find the number of unique groups. Maybe another example would be, red table, red chair, red NA, blue NA. Here, red table, red chair, and blue NA are unique, and the higher level factor, color, is ignored if a lower level factor, object, exists, but not ignored if there is no lower level factor entry, NA. Does that clarify it any better?

Comment: And what do expect as the result of this? I mean in your posted example. 2 or 3?

Comment: In my posted example, 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with subsetting each taxonomic level and adding a column to your data frame, and then nested ifelse statements. If you see ways to improve what it's accomplishing, please let me know.

In the example I posted:

```
data$GenusN <- ifelse(table(data$Genus)[data$Genus] >1, 0, 1)
```

Repeat for each taxonomic level, then sum based on nested ifelse statements.

```
dataNew <- sum(ifelse(data$Taxon == data$Genus, data$GenusN, ifelse(data$Taxon==data$Family, data$FamilyN, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this will give you the correct result but try this one:

```
SELECT sum(cnt)
FROM
    (SELECT Family,
            IF(count(DISTINCT Genus)=0, 1, count(DISTINCT Genus)) AS cnt
     FROM your_table
     GROUP BY Family) AS lo;
```

Comment: I couldn't get this working, but due to SQLite not having IF or AS. I was trying to figure out how to use CASE. I actually found a solution in R though that I will post as an answer. Thank you for your help though.